# How to add jQuery multiselect to struts List jsps

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, multi-select

i am going through http://loudev.com/#project tutorial to create something like that mutliselect. But i didnt get how this can be done for my Struts list jsp. My jsp is as below

```
  UPDATE:
   <display:table name="dimComponents" class="table table-condensed table-hover editRow" requestURI="" id="dimComponentList" export="true" pagesize="5">
    <select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
         <option value='<display:column property="componentDesc" sortable="true" href="editDimComponent" media="html"
            paramId="componentKey" paramProperty="componentKey" titleKey="dimComponent.componentDesc"/>'>"dimComponent.componentDesc"</option>

            <option value='
        <display:column property="componentKey" media="csv excel pdf" titleKey="dimComponent.componentKey"/>'>"dimComponent.componentKey"</option>

        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name"><fmt:message key="dimComponentList.dimComponent"/></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name"><fmt:message key="dimComponentList.dimComponents"/></display:setProperty>

        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename"><fmt:message key="dimComponentList.title"/>.xls</display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename"><fmt:message key="dimComponentList.title"/>.csv</display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename"><fmt:message key="dimComponentList.title"/>.pdf</display:setProperty>
         </select> 
    </display:table>
```

How i can do it.

Comment: Where is your select?

Comment: Ya i have added select above but please help me i coundn't able to find examples for my scenario on net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has nothing to do with Struts. You must work with the generated HTML and not the Jsp file. If you want to add some js in your jsp, Just add a  tag at the end of your file.

Once your HTML is generated, you can manipulate your dropdown, selecting it by its ID :

`$("#my-select").multiSelect();`

Comment: But may i know what is meant by generated HTML. I tried the example given in <http://loudev.com/> by creating HTML file worked fine. But i want to display my JSP document:column in same manner as explained in tutorial above.

Comment: The generated HTML can be seen when you execute your code on a browser. Display the source code of the page, depending on your browser. I don't see what is the goal of putting columns in a dropdown. Anyway, your generated <select> must have an ID and be "multiple" select. It is ! multipleSelect should work

Comment: wow wow wow !! I hadn't notice that ! You are putting a <select> inside a displaytag and then putting your columns inside the <select> ?!! You can't mix your tags like that ! What do you want to display ? a table with a select on each row ? or just a simple dropdown with complexes information in its options ?

Comment: I know it cannot be done. but what i mean is to have functionality

Comment: Just populate your select with some data and try it with multiSelect(). `<html:select styleId="my-select" multiple="multiple"><html:optionsCollection name="dimComponents" value="componentKey" label="componentDesc"/></html:select>` or any other way to populate a simple dropdown with struts.